Identify 1970s Martial Arts movie: 2nd place Hero goes on quest. Disqualified Hero follows, takes over quest.
Guy fights to be the guy that gets to go on quest. Guy gets disqualified. 2nd place guy goes on quest. Disqualified guy follows along until first guy gets bumped off. Disqualified guy takes over. It was a fantasy martial arts movie. Strictly a drive-in "B movie" quality film. Can anybody tell me the title of the movie? 

That would be Circle of Iron
The movie was originally written by and for Bruce Lee and James Coburn as a vehicle to explain Lee's beliefs and martial arts philosophy.  Jeff Cooper plays Cord, the seeker.  David Carradine played multiple parts.  Roddy McDowell, Eli Wallach, and Christopher Lee also starred in it.  It's available on dvd and blu-ray.
